# Iptables - how to allow connection to port 27015 from only *:27005

Tags: linux, iptables

I have an application listening at port 27015. I want to allow all ips with client port 27005 and drop the rest. How do I go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

This page shows some good examples of iptables.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-specify-a-range-of-ip-addresses-or-ports.html

So, something like this should do it:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 27005 --dport 27015 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

Comment: does 195.55.55.78 refer to ip ?

Comment: yes, but you can probably skip it on a simple setup. Notice my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Little late but here is what I would do

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27005 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It will cause you to accept *all* traffic *to* 27005. The intent was to accept only traffic *to* 27015 *only* from 27005